# Mail not being sent - Laravel

Tags: email, smtp, laravel-5, ssl-certificate

I am trying to send emails using Laravel. Actually on my localhost mail is sent and works fine. But fails on production server with the following exception.

> stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate CN=`*.bluehost.com'
>   did not match expected CN=`smtp.mydomain.com'

**Configurations**

1) SSL certificate is installed on the webapp.

2) `config/mail.php` contains `'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', '')`

On forums, this is being suggested that mail server e.g `smtp` in my case needs the certificate also. I find no clear steps for doing so.

Any pointers to actual problem and solutions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Changing MAIL_HOST in  `.env` file from `smtp.mydomain.com` to the name provided by your host for outgoing emails. You can find it in your email configuration settings.